# Transfer paid apps from iPhone to Android Account

Tags: ios

Let's say I have a paid app on my iPhone called "App" that costs $6.99, and I want to download that same app onto my new Android Account (because recently, you are able to download Android apps on Chromebook, right?).

Is there a way to do this easily? Maybe with a redemption code?

Comment: You could contact the developer, in the case of "expensive" apps, some will give you a redemption code to get it on the other platform at no charge... but this is very rare. Otherwise, you will just have to buy it again as the answer states below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple App Store and the Google Play Store are two different stores. 
It is in their best interest to make it impossible/not allow anyone to transfer an app from one store to another.

It's like how you can't buy a phone from Samsung and then claim on the warranty with Apple.
It's often possible to transfer progress in games across platforms but you have to buy the app a second time, sadly.

You can transfer almost anything from iOS to Android but not apps.